# Event based Ajax communication between server and browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, client-server

I'm going to write an application, having some worker threads on the server, and some log and status elements on the html page. logs and status are expected to be updated whenever an update is ready from the server side. 
well, one approach is to set up a polling mechanism, like the client sends a request on specified intervals and the server sends back the last update, (if any available).

however I wonder if there is any more efficient way like an interrupt-driven approach, on which whenever an update is ready on the server a message is sent to the client through an Ajax call. and as long as no update exists no message is transferred back and forth.

first of all, is this possible to initiate a call from the server side? I mean via Ajax.
or is there any library like JQuery that facilitates such a requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your use case is a match for [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Comment: Interesting, I checked the article, what kind of technology is this? I realized that it's not standard, so it's not Ajax or HTML5, what is it?

Comment: apparently server-sent events are not supported by IE yet. anyway thanks

Comment: It is standardised by [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/). There are several polyfill libraries around: https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource, https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js.

Comment: Okay so it's HTML5, thanks I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using web sockets (Available in HTML5) - This will allow you to skip polling an update the data immediately as the server sends up his finish request.

Read more on:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: it's a good one, I could find a more comprehensive source out of your link which is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29 thanks.